# Data from the table based on the received

Tags: sql, postgresql

Table Users:
id, login, name, age

Table views:
id, date, user_id, post_id

Table other:
id, timeD (date), post_id

What is already there:

```
SELECT date, user_id
    FROM public.views
    Where
    date IN (Select max(date) from public.views where post_id = 2
            group by user_id)
```

Result: date and user_id

I need to add in request to display data about the user (login, name, age), the user id is optional and the timeD column

Example: date timeD login name age

Note: the other table may be empty and then i need to output timeD as null, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `left join`:

```
SELECT date, 
       timeD, 
       login, 
       name,
       age
FROM public.views
LEFT JOIN Users 
     ON Users.id = views.user_id
LEFT JOIN other
      ON other.post_id = views.post_id
Where date IN (Select max(date) from public.views where post_id = 2
            group by user_id)
```

Comment: What if another table is empty and I need to output null in this field (timeD), for example, what should I do in this case?

Comment: @ДжейкМорган what is another table? If table `Users` is empty, then these column `login`,`name`,`age` will return null value because no any matched user id

Comment: The other table may be empty, and if it is empty, then i need to output timeD as null, for example

Comment: @ДжейкМорган `left join` will cause `timeD` return null value if the `other` table is empty because `other.post_id` does not contain any value which can match to `views.post_id` and hence it will return null value

Answer (score 0):

SELECT date, user_id, login,name,age,timed
FROM public.views, users, other
where
public.views.user_id = users.id
and public.views.post_id = other.post_id
and date IN (Select max(date) from public.views where post_id = 2 group by user_id)